# Phragmén-Lindelöf type problem

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to solve the following complex analysis problem.
Let $\Omega = \{z \in \mathbb{C} | |Im(z)| \leq 1 \}$ and let $F$ be analytic on $\Omega$, continuous on $\overline{\Omega}$ and $|F(z)| \leq 1 $ on $\partial \Omega$. Now, we need to show that if in addition $F$ verifies the property that $|F(z)|\leq Ce^{b|z|^{\rho}}$ for some constants $C,b > 0$ and $0 < \rho < 2$, then $|F(z)| \leq 1$ on $\Omega$. The hint they give me is to consider $F_{\epsilon}(z) = e^{-\epsilon z^2 }F(z)$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

I have been stuck on this problem, so I would really appreciate any help or suggestions in attacking it. I know that I would probably need to do some Phragme-Lindelof type technique, but I'm unsure as to how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed exactly the [Phragmén–Lindelöf principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phragm%C3%A9n%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_principle).

Let $z_0 \in \Omega$. Let $\epsilon >0$.

Now choose $R>0$ such that $R> \Re(z_0)$ and :
$$C \exp\left({b R^\rho-\epsilon (R^2-1))} \right) \leq 1$$
which exist as we have $ \rho <2 $, so the limit of $C e^{b R^\rho-\epsilon (R^2-1))}$ is $0$ when $R \to \infty$.

Choose then the contour:
$$[-i-R,-i+R] \cup [-i+R,i+R] \cup [i+R,i-R] \cup [i-R,-i-R]$$

then $z_0$ is inside this contour. And $|F|\leq 1$ on the contour:

- For $z \in [-i-R,-i+R] \cup [i+R,i-R] \subset \partial \Omega$ you have $$|F_\epsilon(z)|=|F(z)\ e^{-\epsilon \Re(z^2)}\leq e^{\epsilon}$$.
- For $z \in [-i+R,i+R] \cup [i-R,-i-R]$ you have:
  $$|F_\epsilon(z)|=|F(z)\ e^{-\epsilon \Re(z^2)}\leq C e^{b |z|^\rho} e^{-\epsilon \Re(z^2)} \leq C \exp\left({b R^\rho-\epsilon (R^2-1))} \right) =1$$.

so using the maximum modulus principle you then obtain:
$$|F(z_0)| \leq e^\epsilon$$

Ans this is true for all $\epsilon >0$ so:

$$|F(z_0)| \leq 1$$.